# SQL Server 2008 DATEPART function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need a query to update a column of `DATETIME` type by adding 2 hours only in `Hours` column using the `DATEPART()` function. Please help me out.

My query looks like this:

```
UPDATE logdetails 
SET user_logouttime = DATEPART(HH, user_logouttime) + 2 
WHERE id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM logdetails 
            WHERE user_id = 10 
            ORDER BY user_logintime DESC)
```

It just updates the time column with default value whereas I want only hours to be updated instead of entire time. Say if it's `2013-12-05:09:45:58`, I want it to be `2013-12-05:11:45:58`.

Comment: you can use `dateadd()` but why you are using `datepart()`

Comment: coz it was working fine when I used it alone with GETDATE(). Was not able to get it done with update where I had to provide column name.

Comment: What is the field type for `user_logouttime` ?

Comment: user_logouttime is of DATETIME type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    declare @no_hours int
        set @no_hours = 2
declare @a datetime
set @a='2013-12-05 09:45:58'

    select dateadd(HOUR, @no_hours, @a) as new_time_added
```

### <kbd>[fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7984/2)</kbd>